# Using numeric data in 3 columns to produce text value in 4th column

Tags: excel, if-statement

Awesome community. You've all been very helpful on my novice projects. Here's the next one:

I have a spreadsheet that defines a renewal month as it relates to a customer's subscription. Unfortunately, the data is laid out in a clumsy fashion. Example:

```
       M                       N                      O
       June_Renewal            June_Renewal           August_Renewal
       0                       1                      0
       1                       0                      0
       0                       0                      1
```

As you can see, the number 1 indicates that the client has a subscription renewal in that particular month.

What I'd like to do is to define Column P as "Renewal Month," and create a formula that looks at the data in M, N, O and then places the appropriate text value (month name) into Column P.

I stink to high Heaven when it comes to Excel formulas.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Best Regards,

Joe

Comment: Is the customer information in colums `A`-`L` ?  What version of excel do you have?

Comment: @Jim Yes, column A - L is customer information. Using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(M$2:O$2, 1, MATCH(1, M3:O3, 0)), "_Renewal", "")
```

`MATCH` will find where the 1 is located, `INDEX` picks up the right column header, and `SUBSTITUTE` will get rid of `_Renewal`.  For example:

[image: formula example]

You can replace `M$2:O$2` with the appropriate column names and `M3:O3` with the rows, and then copy the formula down.

Comment: This worked perfectly! And it also confirms that I NEVER would've figured this out on my own. Thank you so much!